# MVC Web Api 2: How to allow parallel download of files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

*Well, below is my code which relates out to downloading of a zip file. All things work fine, but it is not able to download up the file when there is one ongoing download request.*

```
public class ZipController : ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile()
        {
            var zipPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(zipPath))
                {
                    var stream = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Open);
                    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                    {
                        FileName = "abc.zip"
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogError.LogErrorToFile(ex);
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please detail the testing you performed to determine this. Does the code log an error in the catch block? If so, what is it?

Comment: Yeah, it says up File is being accessed by another process, when there is one ongoing download request.

Comment: You might need to open the file in shared access mode

Comment: Also you don't close the stream.  Try wrapping the file access withing a `using` statement.

Comment: I already did that thing. By wrapping up the code inside using statement. But, when I checked it locally, the request was being called two times. Not sure, why it was being called for the second time. Also, I modified the code by finally block instead of using statement. But same thing happened again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I provided up the file access rights.

```
public class ZipController : ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile()
        {
            var zipPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var stream = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(zipPath))
                {

                    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                    {
                        FileName = "abc.zip"

                    };

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogError.LogErrorToFile(ex);
            }
            return result;
        }
     }
```